# Refreshing displayed data

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-1.11

I have this view working and displaying everything correctly. Though when I update the db the displayed data doesn't update in the view.

By restarting the httpd server it then updates the displayed data.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from player.models import .

list = [123,155,166,445]

class Stats(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Table
    template_name   = 'stats.html'    
    object_list     = Table.objects.all()    
    data            = object_list.filter(id__in= list)    
    contract        = [x.Contract for x in data]    
    will            = [x.Will for x in data]

    def get(self, request,):
        context                       = locals()
        context['contract']           = self.contract.count('Deed1')
        context['will']               = self.will.count('Death')
        return render_to_response(self.template_name, context)
```

I was hoping to get it to display the new count anytime the page refreshes. Any nudge in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't operate on models in the definition of the class itself; that'll only be executed once, when the class is first imported. You should do things like that in a method within the class. This should be `get_context_data`; and in fact you should move those other operations there too, you should not override `get()`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.